# how to reduce Dropdown List loading time in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 500 records to display in a Dropdown List. Its taking too much time so can any one help me to reduce the loading time of a Dropdown List?

Comment: Does any user need to review all the 500 records? A better aproach is to load only a subset, i.e. ask the user to type the 2 or 3 first letters and then load the filtered records

Comment: How are you adding the items? One by one? If so, consider using [`ListItemCollection.AddRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.addrange%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to add the items.

Answer (score 4):

500 is a lot to have in a drop down  - who really wants to scroll down 499 items to get to the one they want?

Perhaps consider implementing / using a auto complete drop down list instead; after the user begins typing, the drop down would be filled with just a subset of the items - better for the user in most cases.

Here is an example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/533503/Creating-a-Database-Driven-Auto-Complete-TextBox-U